# c# list in property which is array

Tags: c#

This is my property class:

```
 class Actions
 {
     public string[] Style { get; set; }
 }
```

and this is my main method:

```
Actions action = new Actions();

List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("one");
list.Add("two");

foreach (var item in list)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < action.Style.Length; i++)
    {
        action.Style[i] = item.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(action.Style[i]);
    }                  
}
```

How do I fill the property with list items?

This gives me a exception:
"object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Comment: `Style` has not been instantiated.

Comment: Not sure if Actions is the most appropriate name for your class. It should really be a singular word. Obviously Action is not permitted, so you might want to think of something more descriptive.

Comment: May I'm wrong, but with the second list item you will overwrite the content of your style... Is this intended? And you iterate over your array, but what size has this array? Code looks confusing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: how to see the output of Style property?

Comment: @openshac it's just an example

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to add your items one by one, you could just use the `ToArray()` method of your list like so:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("one");
list.Add("two");

Actions action = new Actions {
    Style = list.ToArray()
};
```

Comment: depends if the original problem is "how to fill property with list items?"

Comment: the problem was that the `Style` was not instantiated

Comment: @Alex  
how to see the output of Style property?

Answer (score 0):

You must create an instance of the `Style` property

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("one");
list.Add("two");
Actions action = new Actions();
action.Style=new string[list.Count];

foreach (var item in list)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < action.Style.Length; i++)
    {
        action.Style[i] = item.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(action.Style[i]);
    }                  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As has already been pointed out, `Style` is always null, given the code you have shared.  @Eldeniz and @paul have shared different ways to fix that.  Obviously, your sample code is just a sample fragment, so here are 2 other options you could consider if the previous two don't work for whatever reason (I'm just free-handing this, please excuse any typos).

1) You can have your `Actions` class always return a not-null object

```
class Actions
{
    private string[] _style;
    public string[] Style 
    {
        get { return _style ?? new string[0]; }
        set { _style = value; }
    }
}
```

Note that this will allow you to always see the output of the style property as requested, assuming an empty array and null are, for your purposes, the same thing.

2) You can make your loop tolerant to null values

```
foreach (var item in list)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < action?.Style.Length ?? 0; i++)
    {
        action.Style[i] = item.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(action.Style[i]);
    }                  
}
```

Finally, just as a tip, if you have your debugger attached and you are stepping through your code, Visual Studio will help you pinpoint these sorts of errors pretty easily.  Take the time to become friends with your debugger.  If it gives you an error you don't understand, do a quick web search.  Your future self will thank you.